# spark-submit "Error: No main class set in JAR" in AWS EMR cluster

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, hadoop

I'm getting this error in an AWS EMR cluster -

*$ spark-submit Movierecommendation
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/home/hadoop/Movierecommendation
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output*

What could be causing this error.  The Scala code is able to compile using sbt.  Let me know.

Comment: Open your .jar file to check if the manifest.mf file is declare correct the main class or not

Comment: Okay; I have it open.  Is not list in the main class.  How should it be listed?

Answer (score 0):

This error we are getting when our jar does not contain the required class file. You need to unzip the jar and check all required classes are there. Sometimes, sbt/maven runs successfully but creates empty jars due to directory structure.

Comment: I open it and I see class files in there, including the main one.

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: But I don't see the "manifest.mf" file declared in the main class.  Is that it?

Comment: Make a jar "executable". you need to jar a file called META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

the file itself should have (at least) this one liner:

Main-Class: com.mypackage.MyClass

Where com.mypackage.MyClass is the class holding the public static void main(String[] args) entry point.

Comment: I see the MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar file.  But it doesn't have that one liner you mention.  Bear in mind, I'm using Scala for the class file then sbt to create the jar file.

Comment: This is what's inside the MANIFEST.MF file....Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Movierecommendation
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Vendor: movierecommendation
Specification-Title: Movierecommendation
Implementation-Vendor-Id: movierecommendation
Specification-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: movierecommendation

Comment: Anything missing?

Comment: See what's inside the jar file on my github repo...  https://github.com/wilberh/Movierecommendation